# d-none d-sm-block not working on mobile or toggle device toolbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a card invisible on mobiles, however while "d-none d-sm-block" works fine when I minimize the page, it doesn't work when I actually deploy and look at it on my mobile nor on the toggle device toolbar in chrome. For some reason "d-none d-lg-block" works perfectly fine whether minimizing or looking at it in mobile format. Any ideas as to why sm specifically isn't working? I've tried other browsers too and the same. My code is as follows.

```
<div class="card d-none d-sm-block">
  <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title" align="center">Example</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `xs` category only covers screen widths of 540px or smaller, and many phones these days are larger than that, so they would be in the `sm` category. See [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#grid-options).

So, to target something for desktop and larger screens, you'd be better off using `md-`, i.e. use `d-none d-md-block`.

Comment: d-md actually has the same result. For some reason its only d-lg and up that works. This assignment i'm doing specifically requires me to hide all xs screens and the lecturer will be checking it in toggle device toolbar.